# Delete statement not working properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

My application is based upon code first entity framework.

I have model called module

```
public class Module
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ModuleTypeId { get; set; }
    public ModuleType ModuleType { get; set; }
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public PropertyConfiguration PropertyConfiguration { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
}
```

And another Model class called OwnedModule

```
public class OwnedModule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public PropertyConfiguration PropertyConfiguration { get; set; }

    public long ModuleTypeId { get; set; }
    public ModuleType ModuleType { get; set; }
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }


    public Guid ModuleOwnerId { get; set; }
    public Module Module { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that when u want to add new module into system u just add Module class, and OwnedModule is something that has a owner or is owned my someone.

So, basically OwnedModule contains Module and other properties. Here is the OwnedMOduleMap class

```
public class OwnedModuleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OwnedModule>
{
    public OwnedModuleMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasOptional(x => x.PropertyConfiguration).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
        HasRequired(x => x.ModuleType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ModuleTypeId);

        HasOptional(x => x.Module).WithOptionalDependent();
    }
}
```

If I had to delete Module I would first have to delete it from OwnedModules table and then delete it from Modules table. IF it has a owner that is.

In my repository this is what I've done:

```
     public void DeleteModule(long id)
    {
        var module = _dbSis.Modules.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id==id);
        DeleteOwnedModule(module.ModuleId);
        _dbSis.Entry(module).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _dbSis.SaveChanges();
    }

    public long GetOwnedModuleId(string moduleId)
    {
        var ownedModule= _dbSis.OwnedModules.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ModuleId == moduleId);
        if (ownedModule != null)
        {
            return ownedModule.Id;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void DeleteOwnedModule(string moduleId)
    {
        var ownedModuleId = GetOwnedModuleId(moduleId);
        var ownedModule = new OwnedModule
            {
                Id = ownedModuleId
            };
        _dbSis.Entry(ownedModule).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _dbSis.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But right now my DeleteOwnedModule method is not working, I get error saying, why is this happening? What do i need to make my Delete statement work?

**An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.**

PS: if i were not to set the owner while adding a Module, then there is no problem while deleting it.

```
  public void DeleteModule(long id)
    {
        var module = _dbSis.Modules.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id==id);
        //DeleteOwnedModule(module.ModuleId);
        _dbSis.Entry(module).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _dbSis.SaveChanges();
    }
```

this works perfectly, if I were to delete it manually, then I can open database delete the module I want from OwnedModules table first then from Modules table. This works too but deleting from the method in repopsitory is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this method:

```
public void DeleteOwnedModule(string moduleId)
{
    var ownedModuleId = GetOwnedModuleId(moduleId);
    var ownedModule = new OwnedModule
        {
            Id = ownedModuleId
        };
    _dbSis.Entry(ownedModule).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    _dbSis.SaveChanges();
}
```

You are creating a new `OwnedModule` with the `id` of an existing one. What you need to do is `Find` the existing module and set *that* instances state to `Deleted` (as you do for `Module` in the method `DeleteModule`)

```
public void DeleteOwnedModule(long id)
{
    var ownedModule = _dbSis.OwnedModules.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id==id);
    _dbSis.Entry(ownedModule).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    _dbSis.SaveChanges();
}
```

Incidentally you have a lot of calls to `SaveChanges()`. Once you get all your code working you may want to consider reducing the number of calls to `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @Biplov13 in your code `DeleteModule` calls `DeleteOwnedModule` so in this example `DeleteOwnedModule` does not need to call `SaveChanges()`. You should try to call `SaveChanges()` in the root of the call chain that changes the data - possibly at the point your `Context` goes out of scope (but that depends on the design of your application and things like how long lived your `Context` is etc)? It's just something for you to think about as you code ...